# Is it possible to serve an Nx app in the background

Tags: nestjs, e2e-testing, nrwl-nx

I have a Nx Monorepo with a couple apps including a NestJS API and a PostgreSQL database. I am setting up a `e2e` target on my API to run a suite of end-to-end tests. In order to do so, I want my API app to be served to then execute my tests. I am using the `@nrwl/jest:jest` executor to run the tests and the target includes a `dependsOn` that runs a `e2e-setup` target. The `e2e-setup` target uses the `@nrwl/workspace:run-commands` executor to run `npx nx run rest-api:serve`. The problem I have is that the serve command blocks: the terminal stays attached to the API process. I know I can push it in the background with `npx nx run rest-api:serve &`, but then I would have to script some logic to "wait" until the API is listening.

There does not seem to be a documented way to serve a Nx app in the background. Is that right? I am thinking perhaps the best approach would be to containerize my apps and serve everything I need (API, DB, Redis, etc.) through docker-compose to then execute my e2e tests. What would be the most idiomatic way to do this?